# How to expire a particular row when a date is reached?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table for students, where each student has to get an ID card and this ID card is valid for one year

I want the student record to be expired when it reaches to the expiration date and the expiration date also needs to be updated

For example, if the expiration date is 01/01/2020 it should be turned to 01/01/2021.

Comment: I am using sql-server

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far. This is too vague. Also, is it `mysql` or `sql server`

Comment: And see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I am baffled by this ' expired when it reaches a specific date and the expiration date also needs to be updated'

Comment: One would normally store a record per year rather than updating the expiry date every time it expires, because you lose your history.

Comment: What "process" occurs to validate that the date should be rolled over? Why not just set the expiration date to 2099-01-01 - what's the point?

Comment: It should be expired yearly and a student has to get another card

Comment: @JawedKhalil when expired new row is inserted with new expiry date

Comment: "It should be expired yearly and a student has to get another card" exactly, so you need a card record with a unique identifier, so that you can expire each individual card. If you just update the expiry date on the student record you don't know which card has expired.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably require a cron job that runs every day which will check the date and if date is today's date, it will update it.

Second possibility is Event scheduler in MySql. For more details on Event Scheduler please refer

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html

Answer (score 0):

```
update tablestudent set expired=yes where expirationdate < getdate()
```

you need to schedule this as job that runs daily.

Answer (score 0):

When saving the data to the table you must have a column "expiration".
to save the expiration, expirationDate = getDate()+1year;

when saving

```
Insert into students (expiration) values (expirationDate);
```

when updating run it daily

```
UPDATE students
SET status = 'expired'
WHERE expirationDate < getDate();
```